# Looping over query results inside another query? MySQL & Coldfusion

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

On my "product editing" page I have a Select List displaying all the 'docs' (from a table) that a user can associate with a product.

```
 <select name="pdid1" size="15" multiple id="pdid1" style="width:450px"> 
      <cfoutput query="get">
           <option value="#get.pdid#">

            #pdname#

           </option>
      </cfoutput>
  </select>
```

If a doc is already associated with this product, I **do not** want it to show up in the `<select>` list.

The following code is only eliminating the first doc it finds in the table from the Select List. So it is like I need to loop over the first query, 'inside' the second, to make sure the first query removes all of the 'matches' from the 2nd query.

```
 <!---Checks for any docs already associated with this product--->

 <cfquery name="find" datasource="#application.dsn#">
    SELECT * FROM prodrelated
    WHERE prprodid = '#url.id#'
 </cfquery>

 <!---Now remove any docs from the Select List query that are already associated with this product--->

 <cfquery name="get" datasource="#application.dsn#">
    SELECT * FROM productdocs
    WHERE NOT productdocs.pdid = '#find.pritemid#'
 </cfquery>
```

How can I make sure that the `<select>` list does not show any docs that are already associated with this product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
WHERE NOT productdocs.pdid = '#find.pritemid#'
```

You want to do an `IN` on all the rows from the original query

```
WHERE productdocs.pdid NOT IN 
  (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#valueList(find.pritemid)#" list="true">)
```

You should always use `cfqueryparam` for all dynamic database values

`valueList(find.pritemid)` creates a comma separated list of all the pritemid values from the "find" query and
`list="true"` tells the cfqueryparam that it's expecting a list or values.

Comment: Thank you, Matt.  It was only missing a closing ")" and worked a charm.  Yahooo!

Comment: @BlueDaNoob - Is filtering the only reason for using two queries? Though it does work, you can do the same thing more efficiently with an outer join.

Answer (score 1):

When you use #find.pritemid# it will only be the first pritemid returned from the query. You can change the WHERE clause to be:

```
WHERE productdocs.pdid NOT IN (#ValueList(find.pritemid)#)
```

This uses the li

Answer (score 1):

Unless you actually need the data from the first query for something else, it is more efficient use a single query with an OUTER JOIN, or even NOT EXISTS. That avoids the overhead of an additional query. Especially one that retrieves more columns than are needed i.e. `select *`. Also, performance of a `NOT IN (...)` clause tends to degrade the more values there are in the list.

Instead, use an OUTER JOIN to return only records where a matching record does *not* exist in the prodrelated table:

```
 SELECT pd.pdname, pd.pdid
 FROM   productdocs pd LEFT JOIN prodrelated pr 
            ON pd.pdid = pr.pritemid
            AND  pr.prprodid = <cfqueryparam value="#url.id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
 WHERE  pr.prprodid IS NULL
```

**NB:** Also, only SELECT the columns you need, rather than `SELECT *`.

Comment: Thank you for your help and for cleaning up my lousy English, Leigh!

Comment: You're welcome. It was not so bad. I have seen a lot worse .. occasionally from my own posts ;-)